# Remove sourceMappingUrl using grunt-contrib-uglify

Tags: gruntjs, uglifyjs

Is there a way to, using the `grunt-contrib-uglify` package, remove the
 `//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map` comment in the compiled output?

I have tried using the options provided in their [documentation](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#sourcemap) but the comment remains.

This is the only (out of 3 packages) that is using a Source Map in our code-base and I'd like to remove the functionality.

Comment: Have you tried setting `options: { sourceMap: false },` in your `uglify` Task in _Gruntfile.js_ ?

Comment: @RobC That’s the default.

Comment: Yes I know,. Presumably you have it set to `true` in your current configuration - that's why you are getting the source maps.

Comment: @RobC I have it set to false but it turns out that after more investigation, it’s an issue with `yeoman/grunt-usemin`. During the concatenation step, I spend each block with the mapping URL.